# NullPointerException error during load listview in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I use `ListFragment` to load listview in fragment. but after run the app my application crash. i check the `logcat` but i did not find out what's the matter . here is the `logcat`:

```
    12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime: Process: whc.ir.news, PID: 1545
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2265)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1627)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1156)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-28 00:42:55.170 1545-1545/whc.ir.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
```

and here is my code :

```
package whc.ir.news.activity;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import whc.ir.news.R;
import whc.ir.news.adapter.Adapter_lst_List_news;
import whc.ir.news.classes.MyApplication;
import whc.ir.news.classes.Utility;

/**
 * Created by marzieh on 25/12/2015.
 */
public class TCenterFragment2 extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener ,AbsListView.OnScrollListener {


    boolean is_null_result2 = false;
    private int cnt_load = 10;

    private Adapter_lst_List_news adp;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String id_tree_news = "8611";
    private String Node_id = "394";
    private String res1, line, res2, line2;
    private InputStream is, is2;
    private Bundle b, send;
    private ListView lst_List_news;
    View myview;

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_t_center, container, false);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) myview.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lst_List_news= (ListView) myview.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        final File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath(id_tree_news + ".txt");
        AlertForNoConnection();
        CheckForFileExist(file);
        FillAdapter();

        return myview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

       // ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.Planets, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(adp);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    private void AlertForNoConnection() {

        // Alert Dialog if No Internet
        if (!Utility.isOnline(getActivity().getApplicationContext())) {
            try {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dlg_internet));

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.approve),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("fail intenet", "fail in is online check");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
    }

    private String CheckForFileExist(File file)
    {
        /***
         * Check For File exist
         ***/

        if (file.exists()) {
            //Log.e("file exist", "file exist");
            try {
                FileInputStream fileIn = MyApplication.getContext().openFileInput(id_tree_news + ".txt");
                InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

                char[] inputBuffer = new char[100];
                String s = "";
                int charRead;

                while ((charRead = inputReader.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
                    String readstring = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0,
                            charRead);
                    s += readstring;
                }

                res1 = s;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Fail Read File", "Fail");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            //setTitle("not exist");
            Log.e("File Notexist", "File Not exist");
            try {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        Uri.parse(getString(R.string.site_address))
                                + "get_list/" + Node_id + "/"
                                + id_tree_news + "/0/10");

                // HttpPost httppost = new
                // HttpPost(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.site_address))+"get_list/"+b.get("id_node")+"/"+b.get("id_tree_news")+"/0/00");
                List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "mobile"));
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "M0b!1e.whc"));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();

                //Log.e("Pass", "connection successfully");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
                LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                        (ViewGroup) myview.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

                TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toas_text);
                text.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.connection_problem));
                Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "IranSansB.ttf");
                text.setTypeface(typeface);
                Toast toast = new Toast(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();
                getActivity().finish();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                res1 = sb.toString();

                //Log.e("Pass 2", "Pass 2 successfuly");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        /***
         * end Check
         ***/
        return res1;
    }
    private void FillAdapter()
    {
        try {

            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(res1);
            if (JA.length() > 0) {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();



                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {

                    json = JA.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String, String> data_item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    data_item.put("id_list_news", json.getString("id"));
                    data_item.put("date_list_news",
                            json.getString("date_publish"));

                    data_item.put("title_list_news", json.getString("title"));

                    data_item.put("img_url_list_news", json.getString("img"));
                    data_item.put("sum_list_news", json.getString("summary"));
                    data.add(data_item);
                }

                // adp = new Adapter_lst_List_news(getActivity(), data, Integer.parseInt(b.get("id_node").toString()));
                adp = new Adapter_lst_List_news(getActivity(), data, Integer.parseInt(Node_id));



            }



            Log.e("Pass 3", "succesfully pass 3 _list_news");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 3", "Fail 3 !!!! _listNews");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        send = new Bundle();
        send.putString("id_node", b.getString("id_node"));
        send.putString("id_list_news",
                adp.getItemId(position) + "");
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),
                Content_News_Activity.class);
        i.putExtras(send);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (lst_List_news.getLastVisiblePosition() == lst_List_news
                .getAdapter().getCount() - 1
                && lst_List_news.getChildAt(
                lst_List_news.getChildCount() - 1)
                .getBottom() <= lst_List_news
                .getHeight()) {

            new new_load_async().execute("");
        }
    }
    class new_load_async extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (is_null_result2 == false)
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {
                Log.e("P d =>Visible", "Visisble");

                cnt_load = cnt_load + 10;

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        Uri.parse(getString(R.string.site_address))
                                + "get_list/" + b.get("id_node") + "/"
                                + b.get("id_tree_news") + "/" + cnt_load
                                + "/10");

                List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "mobile"));
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "M0b!1e.whc"));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is2 = entity.getContent();

                // pDialog.dismiss();

                Log.e("Pass", "connection successfully _New Async Load");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 1 _New Async  Load", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is2, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line2 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line2 + "\n");
                }
                res2 = sb.toString();

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });

                if (res2 == null) {
                    is_null_result2 = true;
                    Log.e("result 2", "result 2 is null ====" + res2);
                } else {
                    is_null_result2 = false;
                    //Log.e("result 2", "result 2 is not null=======>>" + result2);
                }
                return res2;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 2 _New Async Load", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String myresult) {
            set_adapter_asycn();
        }

    }

    public void set_adapter_asycn() {
        try {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(res2);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            if (JA.length() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {

                    json = JA.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String, String> data_item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    data_item.put("id_list_news", json.getString("id"));
                    data_item.put("date_list_news",
                            json.getString("date_publish"));

                    data_item.put("title_list_news", json.getString("title"));

                    data_item.put("img_url_list_news", json.getString("img"));
                    data_item.put("sum_list_news", json.getString("summary"));

                    adp.data.add(data_item);
                    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                Log.e("Pass3 _New Load", "pass 3 _New Load");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("new_load_fail 3", e.toString() + "New Load_Fail 3");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




}
```

my fragment xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F3EFF3"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_List_news"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_List_news"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="12dp" >
        </ListView>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is there any problem using `Fragment` . Please post your Listview xml

Comment: @serenei: checkout my answer!

Comment: @kevz it didn't work

Comment: error might be in your adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Well obtain a valid reference of ListView in the onActivityCreated() callback.

move below code line inside onActivityCreated()

```
lst_List_news= (ListView) myview.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Coz onCreateView creates and returns the view hierarchy associated with the fragment.

change below lines -

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
```

to -

```
lst_List_news.setOnItemClickListener(this);
lst_List_news.setOnScrollListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move below from `onActivityCreated` to `onCreateView` below `FillAdapter()` method

```
    setListAdapter(adp);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
```

Comment: it did not work out too :(( what is the problem?I'm so tired and confused

Comment: @serenei, can you give ur json